# Simple Linear Regression Model parameters not getting updated

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have been following one of the tutorial of PyTorch of creating a Simple Linear Regression model.

I have followed up accordingly here's the code for reference.

```
class LinearRegression(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, requires_grad = True, dtype = torch.float))
    self.weights = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, requires_grad = True, dtype = torch.float))


  def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    return self.weights * x + bias
```

I'm using the SGD as the optimizer with a learning rate of 0.01. And using MAE as the loss function.

Whatever parameters I tune, the bias parameter is not changing at all. Weight is changing fine.

I have seen few Stackoverflow threads which talks of cloning the parameters but it is not working in my case.

I have initialized the model with:

```
torch.manual_seed(42)

model = LinearRegression()

list(model.parameters())
```

When I'm printing the parameters its fine. Where I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: I don't even understand how the code can run: `bias` is not in scope, it should be `self.bias`

Comment: Ya I missed the self part, but however the code was running

Comment: maybe you had a `bias` defined in the outer scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably made a mistake in the forward function, try the following code:

```
def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.weights * x + self.bias  # Fix here: Use self.bias instead of just bias
```